# Is it thread-safe to use SQLAlchemy with engine/connections instead of sessions?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've got a simple webservice which uses SQLAlchemy to connect to a database using the pattern

```
engine = create_engine(database_uri)
connection = engine.connect()
```

In each endpoint of the service, I then use the same connection, in the following fashion:

```
for result in connection.execute(query):
    <do something fancy>
```

Since `Session`s are not thread-safe, I'm afraid that `connection`s aren't either.

Can I safely keep doing this? If not, what's the easiest way to fix it?

Minor note -- I don't know if the service will ever run multithreaded, but I'd rather be sure that I don't get into trouble when it does.

Comment: I don't have an answer for your question, but I wanted to ask a question in return: Do you really need an ORM?  I know this is a matter of personal choice but...If your data is even remotely clean you can just use pyodbc and use a cursor and it will most likely perform better and have cleaner implimentation.

Comment: I don't think anyone has to use an ORM. In this case, it just happened to be easier for me (personally) because the database kept changing out of my control. Some of the queries are quite complex and it was more obvious to me (again, personally) that they are correct using sqlalchemy -- SQL is quite verbose.

Comment: ok fair enough.  +1 for having a good reason to use it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you should be fine.

There is a difference between a `connection` and a `Session`. The short description is that connections represent just that… a connection to a database. Information you pass into it will come out pretty plain. It won't keep track of your transactions unless you tell it to, and it won't care about what order you send it data. So if it matters that you create your Widget object before you create your Sprocket object, then you better call that in a thread-safe context. Same generally goes for if you want to keep track of a database transaction.

`Session`, on the other hand, keeps track of data and transactions for you. If you [check out the source code](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py), you'll notice quite a bit of back and forth over database transactions and without a way to know that you have everything you want in a transaction, you could very well end up committing in one thread while you expect to be able to add another object (or several) in another.

---

In case you don't know what a transaction is [this is Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction), but the short version is that transactions help make sure your data stays stable. If you have 15 inserts and updates, and insert 15 fails, you might not want to make the other 14. A transaction would let you cancel the entire operation in bulk.

Comment: I'm just reading data from the server, not writing; I think I should be safe.

Comment: @Clearer The documentation explicitly states that [`Connection` objects are not thread-safe](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection). Whether the underlying DBAPI connection is thread-safe or not depends on the specific driver.

Comment: @univerio Can I fix this by just calling connection.connect() and using the return value? As far as I can tell, this -should- be safe.

Comment: @Clearer Most likely not. For example, in [`Connection.begin`](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/src/aa3b59af54a7828b8b18f3dfb33a09f254616e20/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#base.py-567), it uses the parent `Connection`'s `.begin()`, so if you use transactions at all it is not guaranteed to be thread-safe. Even if the code is apparently thread-safe, you should not depend on it because it's not an explicit guarantee of the API and can therefore change at any time. Why can't you just wrap the critical section with a `Lock`?

Comment: @univerio There's no particular reason not to use a `Lock` as such, besides the risk of contention; while the service is simple, there could potentially be a few hundreds using it at the simultaneous and the hardware isn't exactly impressive (there's been -no- investigation into the actual needs of the service); low response time is pretty important. For now, I think I'll just do a `Lock` based solution so we can ship the service and, when (hah!) there's time to figure out a better solution, I'll do that instead. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Clearer I think you're worrying about the wrong thing here. Because you're sharing the same socket, there *has* to be a lock somewhere. Whether that lock is at the DBAPI layer or in your app code makes no fundamental difference. Besides, network latency is going to dwarf the overhead of a lock, so any contention is going to be for the actual socket, not the lock.

Comment: @univerio I've been reading a bit more about how SQLalchemy really works and it appears what I need to do is just use `engine.connect` -- it will then return a suitable `Connection` from a pool of connections (defaults to keeping 5 of those live with up to 10 active at the same time). I just need to close it when I'm done (or so I hope) and it will return it to the connection pool. Since I'm just doing reads I don't see any real problems with this approach. If there are problems with this approach, I'll have to ditch SQLAlchemy entirely.